# StatusCodes for IOperationResult in Couchbase

Tags: c#, couchbase

Can someone let me know what the available `StatusCodes` are on `IOperationResult` or point me to some documentation ?

I had a look at the docs online but haven't found anything. I downloaded code from GitHub but the only thing I've found is the enum `StatusCodeEnums` with two codes (`Success(0)` and `NotFound(1)`).

However, I have a test that returns a status code 2 and the following message:

```
Message = "Failed to process response: \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?'q\0\0\0\0P_"
```

(yes, it has the \0 characters - it's not a copy paste/ formatting error)

The test is trying to store the same thing twice against the same key in StoreMode.Add - so I would expect an exception.

I'm using Couchbase 2.0 with the .NET client 1.2.

Can anyone provide a list of codes that can be expected with description what they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and found these links which detail the response codes for the `Memcached Binary Protocol`. They seem to correspond to what Couchbase returns, however, after scanning their latest source code I still cannot find any reference to that. They are using a nullable int for the status code.

http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/documentation-statuscode

http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/BinaryProtocolRevamped#Response_Status

Answer (score 2):

The message below was a corrupted response from the cluster, it has been fixed in 2.2 release. Defect [MB-8149](http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-8149) covers this issue in more detail.

```
Message = "Failed to process response: \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?'q\0\0\0\0P_"
```

The [SDK manual](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.3/#checking-error-codes) has a list of all the `StatusCodes`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post bug, the statuscodes are now documented here:  http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.3/#checking-error-codes